# Order Mangement System for CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am developing a online store application, which provides customized products, on CodeIgniter. I was looking for a possible shopping cart application that I can integrate with my app. 
I understand that CodeIgniter has its own Cart Class. But it does not provide any credit card management facilities. And I would like a system which takes care of shipping, order management etc.
Are there any options out there?

Comment: I am not aware of any full packages like you request. For payments I like to use the authorize.net php library and there are others which wrap the functionality you need. Such as: https://github.com/calvinfroedge/PHP-Payments . For shipping and orders you will either need to build your own or find one that fits the project specs tightly (which is hard). Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for but there is GoCart which is built around codeigniter:  http://gocartdv.com/

Comment: This looks like it could be what I'm looking for. Let me work with it for a bit. Thanks @DannyH